# Three js not finding images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

I've created a Vue Cli app and I'm trying to use Three.js to render 3D objects in there.

The problem occurs when I try to load an image to use it as a texture.

```js
let scene = new Three.Scene();

const spaceTexture = new Three.TextureLoader().load(
  "@/assets/images/space-background.jpg"
);
scene.background = spaceTexture;
```

And where it blows my mind that it is not an import or image problem cause I can normally add it to the DOM:

```html
<template>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <img src="@/assets/images/space-background.jpg" />
</template>
```

[image]

I don't know what to do, I've changed to diverse types of path and nothing. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the `require` key word in your `load` method:

```
<template>
  <div>Hey</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import * as THREE from "three";
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const spaceTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
  require("@/assets/img/space.jpeg")
);
scene.background = spaceTexture;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
</script>
```

This lines do the trick

```
const spaceTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
  require("@/assets/img/space.jpeg")
);
```

Comment: That does not do the trick for me :(
Don't know why

Comment: Could you run my example in your application?, remember to update the image path and run my example, Are you using Vue 3 or Vue 2?

Comment: I was wrong! My apologies, I didn't have any light in the scene so I wasn't seeing anything. What a shame. I'm sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: If I help you in any way, it's not a waste of time, happy to know that your application is running as expected.